# Datatype of dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having a pandas dataframe which has more than 100 columns in it. Some are of object datatype and some are float64 datatype. Is there a way to display the datatype of each columns in the dataframe.

Comment: If your dataframe is called `df` for example, use: `df.dtypes`

Comment: @Erfan Thanks Erfan... And if we want to find the length of float64 columns, how can we do that

Answer (score 1):

You can use **.dtypes** to display all datatypes in each column

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_df.csv')    
df.dtypes

School_ID                           float64
ExNO                                  int64
MemberID                              int64
CourseNO                              int64
tba_id                                int64
.
.
.
```

**Update:**
To find a number of float64 columns, I would do as follows,

```
col_float = len([i for i in df.dtypes if i == 'float64'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help..... Could you please let me know what can we do for finding the length of those float64 columns

Comment: @nikhilthms94 Do you mean a number of float64 columns?

Comment: Yes to find the max number of float column.

Comment: @nikhilthms94 There might be better ways, this is what I can think of  col_float = len([i for i in df.dtypes if i == 'float64'])